# Is it possible to re-init an anonymous function by name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I know I can call a function like this:

```
var groupSetter = function(){
    console.log('asdfasdf');
};
//I want to remove this next line
groupSetter();
```

And recall it from like so:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  // this call is fine
  groupSetter();
});
```

I know this looks silly but more like this.

```
  (function(){
   var groupSetter = function(){
        console.log('asdfasdf');
    };
    })();
```

Is it possible to make var groupSetter an anonymous function but still recall it on window resize?

**UPDATE:**

```
   var groupSetter = (function(){    
      var currentPage = Carousel.pageData[scope.page.pageindex - 1];    
      scope.containerStyles = {
        width: currentPage.size.updated.width + 'px',
        height: currentPage.size.updated.height + 'px'
      };
    })();

    angular.element($window)
      .on('resize', function (e) {


        groupSetter;


      });
```

Comment: Does this work `$(window).resize(groupSetter)` ?

Comment: `$(window).resize(function(){console.log("test")})`

Comment: `groupSetter` _is_ an anonymous function

Comment: do you mean like this? `$( window ).resize(function() {
    console.log('asdfasdf');
});`

Comment: What is the use case here. Why not just leave it the way you have it?

Comment: No use case other than readability.  Curious if I can make var groupSetter self executing.  Updating question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it an IIFE (invokes immediately):

```
var groupSetter = (function groupSetter(){

    console.log('asdfasdf');

    return groupSetter;

})();
```

And re-use it later:

```
$(window).resize(groupSetter);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6dewxnL9/

Comment: thats what I was looking for! perfect!

Comment: Oddly the resize function isn't be executed?  any ideas as to why? I'll update the question with the exact code for clarity

Answer (score 1):

@filur's answer won't work because it immediately invokes the function, returning `undefined`, so you won't get a function back.

If you want an anonymous function expression set to `groupSetter`, what's wrong with:

```
(function() {
  var groupSetter = function() {
    console.log('asdfasdf');
  };

  $(window).resize(groupSetter);
})();
```

Comment: Ha!  I guess this is why everyone wraps their controllers in an anon. function!  Ok sure this is great practice!  Question tho, if needed, how can I write a function inside of this anon block to not fire? lets call it var noFireUntilFormallyCalled = function() {...};

Comment: You would just set your function as you described it. It won't get called until you explicitly call it: noFireUntilFormallyCalled();